# MongoDB Group By issue getting records using group by '$group' in aggregate function on date

Tags: database, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a issue on mongo db to getting records using group by '$group' in aggregate function on date as 'created' but we have datetime format in table mongoDb database.
    when I run the mongo query I am getting error "can't convert from BSON type string to Date"

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(-1 month));
$users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER_DATA'], array(array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
        array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
        array('$group' => array('_id' => array('year' => array('$year' => '$created'), 'month' => array('$month' => '$created'), 'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$created')), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
        ));
```

before we are using

```
array('$group' => array('_id' => array('created' => '$created')), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)),
```

Its was working but records not as required as per group by date, because in table we have datetime.

Comment: Could you post the sample documents

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way:

```
$users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER'], array(
            array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
            array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
            array('$project' => array('_id' => 0, 'y' => array('$year' => ISODate('$created') . getFullYear()), 'm' => array('$month' => ISODate('$created') . getMonth() + 1), 'd' => array('$dayOfMonth' => ISODate('$created') . getDate()))),
            array('$group' => array('_id' => array("year" => '$y', "month" => '$m', "day" => '$d'), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
        ));
```